# how to store html file inside c++ variable

Tags: javascript, c++

How to store **html** file inside c++ variable.

> Is there is specific data type to store

?

Comment: Why do you ask, what is the relation to Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

An HTML file is just a textual file. So you can store it in a string (i.e. `const std::string htmlstring=` or `const char htmlcontent[]=`

<sup>This approach is worthwhile if your HTML file already exists entirely.</sup>

With [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11), you could use raw string literals (so you can just copy paste your entire HTML file into your C++2011 source code without escaping quotes, etc...).

Of course, it might be interesting to you to view the HTML as some [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (like the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)). You might use some XML related C++ library for this, or you could make your own.

<sup>I strongly recommend building some kind of AST inside your program if you want to parse or generate a "varying" HTML.</sup>

Parsing HTML is difficult in practice. If you can restrict to XHTML (that is, XML variant of HTML) you could use some existing XML parser library.

Comment: i try out ur method with including "using namespace std". but i found out it works for CLI.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), you can use [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream).

```
std::stringstream html;

html << "<html>....</html>";
```

Comment: i try out ur method with including "using namespace std". but i found out it works for CLI.

Comment: It should work for every standard C++. Did you put `#include <sstream>`?

Comment: im not that much of having IT knowledge... im working with visualstudio IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Probably depends on what you want - a string if you just need to search it, a nested map if you need to access the DOM, etc...